# Where is the city that the demon Bakasura lived?

Tags: mahabharata, history

Does anyone know where is the city that Bakasura (from Mahabharata) lived? I've looked everywhere and can't find any answers.

Comment: From some sources it is near 'Ekachakra City' (Reference: [here](http://www.solutionastrology.com/SectionArticleDetail.aspx?id=7493&Title=Birth%20of%20ghatotkacha%20&%20bakasura%27s%20killing))

Comment: Khojewadi satara Maharastra india

Answer (score 4):

[This chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01159.htm) of the Adi Parva of the Mahabharata just calls the village Ekachakra:

> Vyasa then said ... "Listen to me! Not far off before you is a delightful town where no danger can overtake you. Live ye there in disguise, waiting for my return." ... Vyasa, the son of Satyavati, thus comforting the Pandavas, led them into the town of Ekachakra....  And the island-born Rishi, addressing the eldest of the Pandavas, said, 'Wait here for me! I will come back to you! By adapting yourselves to the country and the occasion you will succeed in becoming very happy.'

As far as the location of Ekachakra, it's unclear, but [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bakasura) discusses some possibilities:

> It is rumored that the city of Ekachakra is a small village near the town of Rampurhat in the state of West Bengal. It is in this city that the Pandavas were staying during their exile. According to some historians and historical folklores the town of Pandaveswar near Durgapur in the district of Burdwan is the site where that village existed and a well known temple having several ancient Shiva Lingams, said to have been established by the Pandavas and their mother Kunti, exists there near the banks of the river Ajay. The said temple is partly controlled by the Mahants of the Nimbarka sect. A Mutt of that sect, established by the erstwhile Zamindar of Ukhra, exists in the locality of Ukhra near Pandaveswar. The site of the slaying of Bakasura is said to be in a place called Bhimgara situated on the other side of the river Ajay.
>
> As per other sources, the city of Ekachakra (Ekchakra-nagari) is attributed to a contemporary village Erandol, Jalgaon district, Maharashtra. Today, tourists on the outskirts of Erandol can see the fallen rice markings of that era and a nearby water pond. Nearby Padmalay Ganesh temple on the hills is also an important tourist and pilgrim destination.
>
> Pratapgarh district in Uttar Pradesh is ancient religious site Bhayaharan Nath Dham's legends said Bakasura monster was killed in South Pratapgarh which was called "Dwaitwan". Here remains were found of several Pandav sculptures. After Bhima killed the demon cannibal Bakasura, a Shiva Lingam was established here, which today is well known and famed as "Bhayaharan Nath Dham", with the story of the Pandavas and Bakasura, the indelible marks of history. This Lord Shiva temple of the Mahabharata epic times is a magnificent venue and is very important to see, where people have come from every corner of country.

But Wikipedia doesn't cite any sources for these claims, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Shouldn't Ekachakrapuri be somewhere near Panchala Desa considering that they went from there to Draupadi's Swayamvara (of course with the detour to Dhaumya's Ashrama but nevertheless)?

Answer (score 1):

I think the name of that village is now kotasur which is about 10 km from birchandrapur now ,earlier it was known as ekchakradham/ekchakranagari/ekchakrapur.It is my maternal uncles village and I heard the story of hiding of pandavas and how Bhima killed bakasur.

The brief history is as I heard from my grand father and grand mother in my childhood,there was a poor  brahmin i don't know his name but his wife's name was satyabati at ekchakradham,in there home pandavas were stayed .one day the all member of the brahmin were crying because that day their turn to feed Bakasura. Asking them Kunti said don't cry I'll send my strongest son Bhima,Bhima just came back to ekchakra after staying with hirimba and all the rest pandavas went to beg for their food.So Kunti send Bhima with Bakasuras lunch.Bakasura was staying at the top of a hill ,now this place known as Kotasur and the condition was everyday one person,two buffelows and full of one Bullock car food would be sent to Bakasur from ekchakra dham villegers.That day Bhima was going by eating all food of Bakasur when he reached to him all food was finished,Bakasur angried to Bhima and said I'll eat you first.Then there was a battle between Bhima and Bakasura,finally Bhima killed Bakasura ana was returning,in the meantime Arjuna and other came back to home and heard about the story .Arjuna said Bakasura is very strong rakshas and he may killed Bhima so Arjuna send Sarpabana to kill Bakasura,Bhima saw the Bana is comming towards him ,the arjunas bana will not fail and should kill him.Bhima took the ring of right ear and threw towards Sarpabana,The Sarpabana fell down covered by Bhimas ear ring.The name of that place is now Mayureswar hattala, about 1-2 km from Kotasur.The ring is seen today also as a stone.Some says if the stone is replaced a dangerous sound of Sarpa is heard but I don't know it is true or not.

Comment: You have answered the question on the basis of local folk lore.  However in this site the answers have to be sourced and the reference given.  Please take the Meta tour to understand the site better. It is an excellent effort and Welcom to Hinduism site.

Answer (score 0):

Some people says 
Its in Konkan Region in Maharashtra

Name of village is RAKASWADA 
Near Vaibhavwadi

As per local tribes, 
Bakasur used to stay here. People 
requested Bheema to rescue them from 
him. So Bheema killed him.

There is still some caves wherein 
Pandavas used to stay as per the stories
told by people.

People in this area still prepare
a small bullock cart, load rice in it
and leave it near Bakasur House (Caves)
before the Agriculture season start.

The caves carved by Pandavas 
(As per the local stories) 
are beautiful with proper ventilation 
and even in May (Heat Season) it feels
like Air Conditioning inside the Caves.

A smmall cave is even shown as baksur House.

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE!.Please add some sources  like articles mentioning this etc. to  the above story from web. Providing sources in answers is mandatory on this site.Also visit Help Center to know more details about how to write good answers on this site. - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help